# How to enable web notification in Flutter web view

Tags: flutter, webview, flutter-web, flutter-web-browser

I create app from web using web view the web used to send notification to user it work in chrome and other browser but it not work in web view app

Is their any way to show web notification like chrome in flutter web view

I have try firebase not work for web notification it show only notification from firebase

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: its a simple web to app using WebView flutter  i want to web notification which show app like in chrome browser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see from the [MDN Notifications API - Browser Compatibility table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Notifications_API#browser_compatibility), iOS and Android WebView doesn't support the Web Notification JavaScript API.

However, I have created an example using the [`flutter_inappwebview`](https://github.com/pichillilorenzo/flutter_inappwebview) plugin (I'm the author) that uses a [`UserScript`](https://inappwebview.dev/docs/webview/javascript/user-scripts) to inject custom JavaScript code at web page startup to implement the Web Notification API. The full code example is available at [flutter_inappwebview_examples/web_notification](https://github.com/pichillilorenzo/flutter_inappwebview_examples/tree/main/web_notification).

The injected JavaScript code tries to create a "polyfill" for the `Notification` window object and communicate with Flutter/Dart side using [JavaScript Handlers](https://inappwebview.dev/docs/webview/javascript/communication#JavaScript-Handlers) to manage and implement the corresponding Notification UI, for example when you are requesting permission with `Notification.requestPermission()` or when you want to show a notification, for example:

```js
Notification.requestPermission().then(result => {
  if (result === 'granted') {
    const notification = new Notification('Notification Title', {
      body: 'Notification Body!',
      icon: 'https://picsum.photos/250?image=9',
      vibrate: [200, 100, 200]}
    );
    console.log(notification);
  }
});
```

You can use the [flutter_inappwebview_examples/web_notification](https://github.com/pichillilorenzo/flutter_inappwebview_examples/tree/main/web_notification) project example as a starting point for your mobile app!

[image: Simulator Screen Recording - iPhone 14 Pro Max - 2022-11-24 at 23 25 39]

Comment: well done on your flutter_inappwebview plugin. I am using it and I am loving it, however, I am having a hard time using it with fluttter_web_ble to communicate with a bluetooth device. I could control the device from the webview but couldn't copy data to the device and vice-versa . Any pointer will be appreciated